# Passing Path value dynamically Javascript

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I have shell command which runs batch file with parameters below code all works fine

```
WshShell.Run ( '"H:\\Workspace\\testcomplete\\TCAF - QIKSilver\\test.bat" ' +  + a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c);
```

The batch file path is not constant I would like to pass it dynamically

```
d= Project.Path; // I get the path of my project
value = d.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");// replace single backslash with double slash
filepath = value.concat("test.bat") // value of filepath varialbe is -H:\\Workspace\\testcomplete\\TCAF - QIKSilver\\test.bat
```

Following is not working:

```
WshShell.Run ('filepath' + a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c);
```

any suggestions please

This code is written inside test complete using java script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WshShell.Run (filepath+' '+ a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **filepath** as a variable, not string, and you need to add quotes since your path contains spaces:

```
WshShell.Run('"' + filepath + '" ' + a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c);
```